# What are some compelling reasons to use Electrum?

Tags: client, electrum

I currently use Bitcoin-qt on OSX and I'm considering switching to Electrum.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using Electrum over another Bitcoin client?

My two major concerns are security and ease of use. Is Electrum safe / trustworthy as a client?

Answer (score 2):

Why Electrum?

- Instant on: Your client does not download the blockchain, it uses a remote server.
- Forgiving: Your wallet can be recovered from a secret seed.
- Safe: Private keys are never sent to the server. Information sent by the server is verified using SPV
- No downtimes: Several public servers are available, you can switch instantly.
- Ubiquitous: You can use the same wallet on different computers, it will auto-synchronize.
- Open: You can export your private keys into other Bitcoin clients.
  Tested and audited: Electrum is open source and was first released in November 2011.

http://electrum.org/tutorials.html#why-electrum